# Prepare Statement Issues

Tags: c#, prepared-statement, ole

I am trying to implement prepared staments in my code as a way of adding parameters to sql commands that are retrieved from a table held in any generic server. I cannot seem to get it right. I get the following error:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-00936: missing expression

Prepare Statement: select VALUE from RWOL_CONFIGURATION where ID = @ItemId
```

My guess is that it just isn't replacing the value but I dont know what I am missing.

I am trying the following to achieve the desired result. I create my object, get a query string out of our table in the database, add that to the command, add parameters to a list object and then use the final method shown below to tie it all together and run the query:

```
//This function gets me a config item from the database
private string GetConfigurationItem(string itemId)
    {
        //new database connection object
        OleDataBaseConnection oleDataBaseConnection = new OleDataBaseConnection();

        //todo get this query from the sql factory
        SqlFactory sqlFactory = new SqlFactory();

        //This method gets the query string from the database
        string sqlQuery = sqlFactory.GetQueryString("GET_CONFIGURATION_ITEM", m_dialect);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlQuery))
        {
            //add parameter to list
            oleDataBaseConnection.AddStoredProcedureParameter("@ItemId", itemId);

            //execute the sql command after adding the parameters to the command 
            oleDataBaseConnection.OleExecutePrepareStatementWithParametersQuery(sqlQuery);

            string returnValue = oleDataBaseConnection.NextRecord() ? oleDataBaseConnection.GetFieldById(0) : "Error";

            oleDataBaseConnection.Close();

            return returnValue;
        }
        else
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }

    }

//adds the parameters to list objects ready for the next method
 public void AddParameter(string parameter, object value)
    {
        m_parameterName.Add(parameter);
        m_parameterValue.Add(value);
    } // End of void AddParameter()

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a command with the parameters passed to AddParameter(parameterName, parameterValue) and creates a recordset.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <param name="commandName">The name of the stored procedure to execute.</param>
    public bool OleExecutePrepareStatementWithParametersQuery(string commandName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(commandName))
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            PrepareConnection();

            m_oleDatabaseCommand.CommandText = commandName;
            m_oleDatabaseCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (m_storedProcedureParameterName.Count != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < m_storedProcedureParameterName.Count; i++)
                {
                    m_oleDatabaseCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(m_storedProcedureParameterName[i], m_storedProcedureParameterValue[i]);
                }

                m_storedProcedureParameterName.Clear();
                m_storedProcedureParameterValue.Clear();
            }

            m_hasRecordSet = true;

            m_oleDatabaseDataReader = m_oleDatabaseCommand.ExecuteReader();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (QueueErrors)
            {
                QueuedErrorsList.AppendLine(ex.Message);
                QueuedErrorsList.AppendLine("Prepare Statement: " + storedProcedureName);
                QueuedErrorsList.AppendLine();

                QueuedErrorCount++;

                return false;
            }

            try
            {
                Close();
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            throw new Exception(ex.Message + "\r\n\r\nPrepare Statement: " + storedProcedureName);
        }
    } // End of void OleExecutePrepareStatementWithParametersQuery()
```

Sorry if there is a lot of code but it is fairly straightforward and I thought it would help with the problem.

Is there anything obvious that would stop this from working?

Comment: Please post the value of `sqlQuery`.

Comment: Also, what are you using OleDb instead of the Oracle provider?

Comment: Because we are not just using an oracle database. We have around 6 different databases to communicate with so OLE suits our needs much better. A command is stored for each of the different database dialects and we retrieve the one we need and we have to add a parameter or two to some of them before executing. I wanted to use a simple String.Replace("{0}", itemId); but the boss wants me to use something like the above instead saying it is the usual way it is done. The value of the sqlQuery is shown in the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the OleDB provider does not support named parameters in the query.

This:

```
select VALUE from RWOL_CONFIGURATION where ID = @ItemId
```

Should be:

```
select VALUE from RWOL_CONFIGURATION where ID = ?
```

See [OleDbParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) on MSDN for examples.

Comment: Thanks. Could my implementation be modified to allow multiple parameters? If I am just using the ? indicator then I assume I will have issues when trying to put say two where clauses in and attempting to use the ? for both. Sorry to ask but the MSDN does not show an example for this. I use      m_oleDatabaseCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(m_parameterName[i], m_parameterValue[i]); to add a parameter to the command object.

Comment: @CSharpened - You can add more `?`. One per parameter and they will be replaced in order of parameters (first ? with first param etc...). This does mean that if you need to use the _same_ parameter several times, you need to add it that many times.